# Does the iphone app store provide instant payment notification to a url?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm considering posting an app to the iphone app store, but I'm  curious before I start paying them for the priviledge of posting the app, whether they provide instant payment notification to a url?

Generally, I've used paypal in the past for applications where right after payment my web site is secretly notified of a purchase.  I take this notification, with the users email address and product purchased, to send the purchaser information required for the application.

Is this possible with apple?  With the iphone app store?  What about the upcoming mac store?

thx

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple handles all contact with the customer, including delivery of the app. At the end of each day, week and month they give you summaries of sales of each product in each country. It's nothing like selling with PayPal. The iOS and Mac App Store are exactly the same in this regard.

The nearest you can get is having your app connect to your server when it first runs, although if you're doing this for no other reason than to track your users, you'll have to check it's allowed under the developer agreement.

Answer (score 1):

First, no, you do not receive instant notification. You can grab a daily report on the web the following early morning (in the US), you can use the free app that Apple provides to retrieve the information, or you can use a variety of third-party tools to do the same.

Second, you will never receive any information whatsoever about the people who buy your app, so no, you can't send purchasers anything.

The Mac App Store appears to use the exact same arrangements.

Comment: Just curious... you would get instant notification if you're using in-app purchases, right? I agree to your point that you won't know who bought it, but you can have your in-app purchases set up to hit your server for permission/content... right?

Comment: It depends on the type of content. Added app features -- that is, anything that's new program functionality -- must be built into the app when it is sent to Apple, so there's no need to contact a server of yours. Added content -- anything non-executable, really -- can be shipped with the initial app or can be downloaded from a source you control. In the latter case you would indeed receive whatever notification you set up on your server.

Comment: The **Feature Delivery** portion of Apple's IAP documentation has diagrams that will make my comment easier to understand. :)  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW11

Answer (score 1):

If you use in-app purchase, you can get an instant notification to your server for the in-app purchase, but not for the initial download of the app.

If you just place a paid app in Apple's App store, you get no direct sales or customer information of any kind, only after-the-fact daily and weekly sales trend estimates, and monthly sales reports a few weeks later.  Then Apple then pays you 70% of what they reported up to 45 days after the monthly close.  You don't pay them.  They pay you.  And with over 300K apps in their store, and no other store doing anywhere near as well, they need no privileges granted from any developer.  It's more like take it or leave it.